# How to make an array of selected rows in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table in my Angular app. Each row of the table has a checkbox, I want to push all of selected rows in an array.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="group-tbl">
  <thead>
    <td>
      <label for="select_all"><span id="select-all-btn">&#xf35f;</span></label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="all" id="select_all">
    </td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>company</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td></td>
  </thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="y in subscriberDetail|filter:search | limitTo:settings.pageLimit:settings.offset">
    <td>
      <input id="{{cb+$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked="all" ng-model="y.check" name="group_item-select">
      <label for="{{cb+$index}}"><span></span> </label>
    </td>
    <td ng-class="{'greent': y.check}">{{y.nameFamily }}</td>
    <td ng-class="{'greent': y.check}">{{y.company }}</td>
    <td ng-class="{'greent': y.check}">{{y.email}}</td>
    <td ng-class="{'greent': y.check}">{{y.mobile}}</td>
    <td class="group-tbl__btn" ng-controller="subscriberDeleteController as subdel"><a href="#/group/detail/{{data.categoryId}}/detailView/{{y.id}}" class="btn">&#xf133;</a><a ng-show="y.usersId==usersId" href="#/group/detail/{{data.categoryId}}/editSub/{{y.id}}" class="btn" style="font-size: .8em">Edit</a>
      <button ng-show="y.usersId==usersId || y.status==1"
      class="btn" ng-value="{{y.id}}" ng-click="confirm(subscriberDetail,settings.offset+$index);getValue()" button-value="deleteId">&#xf4c4;</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes the Alternative one,iv tried with for loop but it didnt work ,if u edit the answer i can accept that. tnx alot btw

Comment: I updated my answer to put the "alternative solution" one in first. Also, I added a [JsFiddle demo with `for loop`](http://jsfiddle.net/7cdLeupp/) to show you of it works. :)

Comment: I also created a [demo for the solution you use](http://jsfiddle.net/ab4vzd8o/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### By updating on click

Add `ng-click` to your input:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="y.check" ng-click="click(y)">
```

And here is the code of `click()` in your controller:

```
$scope.click = function(item) {
    if(item.check) { // Add it
        $scope.selected.push(item);
    } else { // Remove it
        var index = $scope.selected.indexOf(item);
        $scope.selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

[**=> Demo on JsFiddle <=**](http://jsfiddle.net/ab4vzd8o/)

---

### Alternative with a for loop

There are **several** ways to do it with a loop. Here is a code with a simple `for(;;)` loop.

```
// Array for selected rows
$scope.selected = [];

// For each item in subscriberDetail
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriberDetail.length; i+) {
    // Item is checked
    if($scope.subscriberDetail[i].check == true) {
        // Add it to the selected array
        $scope.selected.push($scope.subscriberDetail[i]);
    }
}
```

*This code should be call **at the end** of the selection. Else look at the second solution.*

[**=> Demo on JsFiddle <=**](http://jsfiddle.net/7cdLeupp/)

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer of @Mistalis will suffice, you can also do this with a filter when you actually need the checked items. This way you don't have to keep track of an array or when the checkboxes are toggled:

```
$scope.onSomeActionWhenYouNeedTheCheckedItems = function(){
    var checkedItems = $filter("filter")($scope.subscriberDetail, { check: true });
    // do something with the checked items
}
```

Or in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="checkedItem in checkedItems = (subscriberDetail | filter:{check:true})">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The last syntax will also create the variable `checkedItems` on your scope, so you don't have to do anything manually.